# reactjs - Trigger useEffect only once on first state change

Tags: reactjs

How to trigger useEffect only once when state of a variable changes the first time from null to something?

In the case below, `state.gender` changes from `null` to `0` or `1`. The useEffect should only trigger when it changes the first time. Thereafter, the subsequent switches between values `0` and `1` should not trigger useEffect.

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    screen: 1,
    gender: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
// Do something
      })}
    }, [state.gender]);

...
...
...
          <RadioGroup
            aria-labelledby="gender-group"
            name="gender"
            value={state.gender}
            onChange={(event, fieldValue) => {handleInputChange(event, fieldValue, "gender")}}
            >
            <FormControlLabel value={1} control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
            <FormControlLabel value={0} control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
          </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Why would you like to do that?

Comment: Because I want to call an api soon after they select gender. I do not want to keep calling the same api everytime they switch the radio buttons. Its a geo API and I have been burned once. Just want to call it one and only one time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ref` for that

```
const firedRef = useRef(false);
useEffect(() => {
  if (firedRef.current || state.gender === null) return;
  firedRef.current = true;
  // rest of the code goes here
}, [state.gender]);
```

Comment: This would fire on the first load, which they probably don't want, just need to update the if statement to something like `if (state.gender !== null && firedRef.current) return;`

Comment: As OP said the value comes from the API. You have to add a condition check whether the `state.gender` is null or already a number.

Comment: I'm not sure if `gender` will be not `null` after the API call but fine

Comment: @kinduser Exactly what I answered :)

Comment: The api call will have no impact on gender or its state. Its a geoAPI and I just want to fire it as soon as they select gender the first time.

Comment: You are right :) Although, I would just get rid of `useEffect` and check this condition on click

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Ended up handling this onClick and posted an answer based on your suggestion. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If your initial value is `null`, and then you just switch between `0` and `1`, then stop the operation if the value is `null`

```
 useEffect(() => {
      if(state.gender !== null) return;
      // Do something
       }, [state.gender]);
```

Comment: this would happen if state.gender changed from `0` to `1` and back again

Comment: It's not, because I'm checking if it's different from null

Comment: Right, but they need to keep a reference to whether or not it was null on the previous render and no longer is on the current, not just the current value.

Comment: That's not what the OP said

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of not triggering useEffect. This one triggers and then exits. Upvoted because it works !

Comment: I can write you code that won't activate the useEffect at all, but it will just be clever, because there really is no real way to delete the useEffect's listening to the state

Comment: Thanks. I thought this worked but does not upon testing - My question was trigger only on first state change. `initial state: null`. First state change will be to `0 or 1`. The useEffect does not process beyond first line as first state change will not be `null`.

Comment: I don't quite understand why it doesn't work for you? The first time the gender changes is from null and then everything is no longer null, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Removed useEffect and added onClick handling which checks if state was null before. useEffect was not needed in this case as constantly monitoring a state was not necessary.

```
  const handleGenderChange = (event, fieldValue) => {
    //trigger geo only when gender changes from null to a value (1st time)
      if(state.gender == null) {
        attemptLocation();
      }
      //update gender state
      handleInputChange(event, fieldValue, "gender")
    }
```